# Wireshark V2 plugin info column resets after applying filter

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have a basic Wireshark plugin that was originally written for Wireshark V1 and I'm currently trying to port it to V2.

The issue I'm currently having is that when the plugin is run in wireshark-qt-release the plugin starts fine and all the necessary information is displayed but once a filter is set the information contained within the info column gets cleared. The info column stays empty after clearing the filter also.

The packet type variable used to set the string found in the info column is also added to the Header tree of the packet being dissected. This stays set with or without a filter being set.

Built on branch master-2.0, branch is up-to-date.
Built with MSVC 2013 and I get no errors or warnings.

Have also enabled the debug console in Wireshark but get nothing out but that might be because I can't adjust the debug level which is currently set to 28.

Works fine in the build of wireshark-gtk2 built within the same check out.

Any help appreciated.

```
/* packet-trcp.c
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
* of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
* Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
*/

#include "config.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include <epan/dissectors/packet-tcp.h>

#define PROTO_TAG_TRCP      "TRCP"
#define MAGIC_NUMBER        0x111111
#define FRAME_HEADER_LEN    8
#define TRCP_PORT           1111

static int proto_trcp = -1;

static dissector_handle_t data_handle = NULL;
static dissector_handle_t trcp_handle = NULL;

static void dissect_trcp(tvbuff_t * tvb, packet_info * pinfo, proto_tree * tree);
static int dissect_trcp_message(tvbuff_t * tvb, packet_info * pinfo, proto_tree * tree, void *);

static const value_string packet_type_names[] =
{
    { 0, "Invalid message" },
    { 1, "Connection Request" },
    { 2, "Connection Response" },
    { 3, "Disconnect" },
    { 4, "File Header" },
    { 5, "File Chunk" },
    { 6, "Cancel File Transfer" },
    { 7, "Firmware Imported" },
    { 8, "Alert Message" },
    { 9, "Restore Factory Settings" },
    { 10, "Format Internal Storage" },
    { 11, "Beacon" },
    { 12, "Shutdown" },

    { 0, NULL }
};

static gint hf_trcp_header    = -1;
static gint hf_trcp_magic     = -1;
static gint hf_trcp_length    = -1;
static gint hf_trcp_type      = -1;
static gint hf_trcp_data      = -1;

static gint ett_trcp          = -1;
static gint ett_trcp_header   = -1;
static gint ett_trcp_data     = -1;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void proto_reg_handoff_trcp(void)
{
    static gboolean initialized = FALSE;

    if (!initialized)
    {
        data_handle = find_dissector("data");

        trcp_handle = create_dissector_handle(dissect_trcp, proto_trcp);
        dissector_add_uint("tcp.port", TRCP_PORT, trcp_handle);

        initialized = TRUE;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void proto_register_trcp (void)
{
    static hf_register_info hf[] =
    {
        {&hf_trcp_header,
        {"Header", "trcp.header", FT_NONE, BASE_NONE, NULL, 0x0, "TRCP Header", HFILL }},

        {&hf_trcp_magic,
        {"Magic", "trcp.magic", FT_UINT32, BASE_HEX, NULL, 0x0, "Magic Bytes", HFILL }},

        {&hf_trcp_length,
        {"Package Length", "trcp.len", FT_UINT16, BASE_DEC, NULL, 0x0, "Package Length", HFILL }},

        {&hf_trcp_type,
        {"Type", "trcp.type", FT_UINT16, BASE_DEC, VALS(packet_type_names), 0x0, "Package Type", HFILL }},

        {&hf_trcp_data,
        {"Data", "trcp.data", FT_NONE, BASE_NONE, NULL, 0x0, "Data", HFILL }}
    };

    static gint *ett[] =
    {
        &ett_trcp,
        &ett_trcp_header,
        &ett_trcp_data
    };

    proto_trcp = proto_register_protocol ("TRCP Protocol", "TRCP", "trcp");

    proto_register_field_array (proto_trcp, hf, array_length (hf));
    proto_register_subtree_array (ett, array_length (ett));
    register_dissector("trcp", dissect_trcp, proto_trcp);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

static guint get_trcp_message_len(packet_info * pinfo, tvbuff_t * tvb, int offset)
{
    guint plen;
    plen = tvb_get_ntohs(tvb, offset + 6);

    // Add the header length to the data length to get the total packet length
    plen += FRAME_HEADER_LEN;

    return plen;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void dissect_trcp(tvbuff_t * tvb, packet_info * pinfo, proto_tree * tree)
{
    // According to - 9.4.2. How to reassemble split TCP Packets
    tcp_dissect_pdus(tvb, pinfo, tree,      // Hand over from above
    TRUE,                                   // Reassemble packet or not
    FRAME_HEADER_LEN,                       // Smallest amount of data required to determine message length (8 bytes)
    get_trcp_message_len,                   // Function pointer to a method that returns message length
    dissect_trcp_message,                   // Function pointer to real message dissector
    NULL);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

static int dissect_trcp_message(tvbuff_t * tvb, packet_info * pinfo, proto_tree * tree, void * data)
{
    proto_item * trcp_item = NULL;
    proto_item * trcp_sub_item_header = NULL;
    proto_item * trcp_sub_item_data = NULL;
    proto_tree * trcp_tree = NULL;
    proto_tree * trcp_header_tree = NULL;
    proto_tree * trcp_data_tree = NULL;

    guint32 magic = 0;
    guint32 offset = 0;
    guint32 length_tvb = 0;

    guint16 type = 0;
    guint16 length = 0;

    col_set_str(pinfo->cinfo, COL_PROTOCOL, PROTO_TAG_TRCP);
    col_clear(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO);

    if (tree)
    {
        trcp_item = proto_tree_add_item(tree, proto_trcp, tvb, 0, -1, FALSE);
        trcp_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(trcp_item, ett_trcp);

        trcp_sub_item_header = proto_tree_add_item(trcp_tree, hf_trcp_header, tvb, offset, -1, FALSE);
        trcp_header_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(trcp_sub_item_header, ett_trcp_header);

        /*
        4 bytes for magic number
        2 bytes for packet type
        2 bytes for data length
        */

        // Add Magic to header tree
        proto_tree_add_item(trcp_header_tree, hf_trcp_magic, tvb, offset, 4, FALSE);
        offset += 4;

        // Get the type byte
        type = tvb_get_ntohs(tvb, offset);

        // Add Type to header tree
        proto_tree_add_uint(trcp_header_tree, hf_trcp_type, tvb, offset, 2, type);
        offset += 2;

        col_append_fstr(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO, "%s", val_to_str(type, packet_type_names, "Unknown Type:0x%02x"));
        col_set_fence(pinfo->cinfo, COL_INFO);

        // Add Length to header tree
        length = tvb_get_ntohs(tvb, offset);
        proto_tree_add_uint(trcp_header_tree, hf_trcp_length, tvb, offset, 2, length);
        offset += 2;

        if (length)
        {
            // Data
            trcp_sub_item_data = proto_tree_add_item(trcp_tree, hf_trcp_data, tvb, offset, -1, FALSE);
            trcp_data_tree = proto_item_add_subtree(trcp_sub_item_data, ett_trcp_data);
        }
    }

    return tvb_captured_length(tvb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the column only if the `tree` argument is non-NULL.

***DO NOT DO THAT.***

*Always* set it, *regardless* of whether `tree` is null or not.  There is *no* guarantee that, if your dissector is called in order to provide column information, `tree` will be non-null; we have never provided such a guarantee, and we will never provide such a guarantee.

Comment: Got same issue, fixed after removing check for tree is non-null.

Thanks user862787